# Get nodes connected only to other nodes that have a property in a range

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 4 types of nodes: `S, G, R` and `C`

`S` nodes have an `idStr` property that identifies them.

Every node of type `G` uses just a `S` node: `(:G)-[:USES]->(:S)`

Every node of type `C` may be connected to multiple `R` or `G` nodes: `(:C)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:R|:G)`

Every node of type `R` may be connected to multiple `R` or `G` nodes: `(:R)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:R|:G)`

**Question:**

Given an `idStr` range, I want to get all `R` and `C` nodes that are connected (directly or indirectly) only to `G` nodes that use `S` nodes with an `idStr` in that range.

The closest approach I have achieved is:

```
MATCH (a:S)<-[:USES]-(b:G)<-[:CONNECTED_TO*]-(n:C)
WHERE a.idStr IN ['1a','b2','something']
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT b) AS GroupGs
MATCH p=(n)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(c:G)
WITH FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE NOT x:G) AS cs,GroupGs,COLLECT(c) AS gs
WHERE ALL(x IN gs WHERE x IN GroupGs)
RETURN cs
```

but still some nodes that are connected to `G` nodes that use `S` nodes not in the range are being returned. **[[Neo4j Console Test](http://console.neo4j.org/r/yt2xq0)]**

**What am I trying to do?**

First match is used to get two things: `G` nodes that use `S` nodes with `idStr` in the given range (`GroupGs`) and the `C` nodes that are connected to those `G` nodes.

Once we get that, we have to check if those `C` nodes are connected to more `G` nodes (directly or through `R` nodes). That is the second match.

Now we have to check for each `C` node if all the `G` nodes connected to it (directly or through `R` nodes) are in the `GroupGs` range. If it is so, that `C` node (and the `R` nodes in the paths to the `G` nodes) are a match, and that is what I am trying to get.

**Second approach** (suggested by @FrobberOfBits)

Trying to use just one match, so we are sure the `n` node is the same in the matching:

```
MATCH (a:S)<-[:USES]-(b:G)<-[:CONNECTED_TO*]-(n:C), p=(n)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(c:G)
WHERE a.idStr IN ['1a','b2','something']
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT b) AS GroupGs, FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE NOT x:G) AS cs,COLLECT(c) AS gs
WHERE ALL(x IN gs WHERE x IN GroupGs)
RETURN cs
```

The result is the same. **[[Neo4j Console Test](http://console.neo4j.org/r/fqytls)]**

**Third approach** (suggested by @FrobberOfBits)

Giving semantics to the problem, `C` may be an `endpoint` in a network, `R` a `repeater`, `G` a `gateway` and `S` a `Sim` card.

`Sim` nodes have an `iccid` property that identifies them.

Every node of type `Gateway` uses just a `Sim` node: `(:Gateway)-[:USES]->(:Sim)`

Every node of type `Endpoint` may be connected to multiple `Repeater` or `Gateway` nodes: `(:Endpoint)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:Repeater|:Gateway)`

Every node of type `Repeater` may be connected to multiple `Repeater` or `Gateway` nodes: `(:Repeater)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(:Repeater|:Gateway)`

I am trying to get all the `Repeater` and `Endpoint` nodes that are just connected to `Gateway` nodes that are using `Sim` nodes whose `iccid` are in a range.

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got it:

```
MATCH (a:S)<-[:USES]-(b:G)
WHERE a.idStr IN ['1a','b2','something']
WITH COLLECT(b) AS GroupGs
MATCH (c)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(d:G)
WHERE NOT d IN GroupGs
WITH COLLECT(c) AS badCandidates,GroupGs
MATCH (e)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(f:G)
WHERE NOT e IN badCandidates AND f IN GroupGs
RETURN e
```

First I get `GroupGs`: all the `G` nodes that use a `S` node with an `idStr` property in the given range.

Now I collect all the `C` and `R` nodes that are connected to a `G` node not in the `GroupGs` and I call them `badCandidates`.

Finally, I get all the `C` and `R` nodes that are not in the `badCandidates` collection and are connected to a `G` node in the `GroupGs`.

Here you have an example: **[[Neo4j Console Test]](http://console.neo4j.org/r/qzxrq7)**

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is really confusing things with the variables you choose -- binding "a" to label S's, and "b" to label G's?  Later binding "c" to "G's" in the second match clause?   This query is going to be hard to debug in the future, and makes it hard to see what's going on; consider binding label "G" to "g", or "gs", or similar, and so on.

I think your problem is the second match clause.  The (c:G) in the second match clause doesn't relate to anything in the first (which is (b:G)).  This means that the path via a set of CONNECTED_TO* relationships from some node to some (c:G) has nothing to do with the complex match on the first line of the query.   This second match matches *anything* labeled G, not just the things you specify in the first match.

That second match is bad because of the requirement you stated:

> only to G nodes that use S nodes with an idStr in that range

I don't have your test data, so I can't verify that this works.  But here's something to try instead:

```
MATCH (a:S)<-[:USES]-(b:G)<-[:CONNECTED_TO*]-(n:C),
      p=(n)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(b:G)
WHERE a.idStr IN ['1a','b2','something']
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT b) AS GroupGs,
     FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE NOT x:G) AS cs,GroupGs,COLLECT(c) AS gs
WHERE ALL(x IN gs WHERE x IN GroupGs)
RETURN cs
```

Apologies if the syntax edited here isn't perfect; this is a complex query and is going to take some fiddling, but I think the placement and mis-labeling of that second `MATCH` is your issue.  My solution may not be perfect and may require tinkering, but should get you there.

Comment: I'm sorry if the notation is confusing, @FrobberOfBits The (c:G) node in the second match clause is indeed not necessary related to anything in the first match.

I have edited the question, adding the section **What am I trying to do?** in order to clarify that.

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: ChusZ, that clarifies thanks but I think there's still a problem with your second match.  In your clarification you say:  "we have to check if **those** C nodes are connected to more G nodes (directly or through R nodes). That is the second match."   When you say **those** C nodes, node that in the second match, you refer to just a node "n".  That "n"  isn't bound to anything in your first match.  So n is not **those C nodes**, n is any node (not limited to C's)

Comment: How can I bound them?

I previously used the code `[...] WITH n, COLLECT(DISTINCT b) AS GroupGs [...]` trying to bound them, but the result was the same, so I removed the `n`.

Comment: Make a second clause as part of the first match like I suggested, referencing n.  I don't think the name "n" from the first match carries over into the second match.

Comment: I was trying to use this: 
`MATCH (user)-[:FRIEND]-(friend)
WHERE user.name = {name}
WITH user, count(friend) AS friends
WHERE friends > 10
RETURN user`
_The WITH syntax is similar to RETURN. It separates query parts explicitly, allowing you to declare which identifiers to carry over to the next part._ [http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/]

Comment: You may be right about that.  The query is complex, and as I said, it's hard to understand with abstract labels.  I have a feeling it would make a bit more sense if we knew what S, G, and C were, and what the semantics are.  If we knew that, perhaps there'd even be another query approach to suggest (rather than tweaking this one).  Good luck.